# .NET Focus() on WinForm control makes scrollbar move down

Tags: .net, controls, focus, scrollbar

**The link to the code is here on my github (was too long to post here):**

https://github.com/alpizano/UI-Scrollbar/blob/master/ScreenLogic.vb

*I also added a README.md that has the Controls labeled on the screen*

I am interning and trying to fix a bug with software (using Visual Studio and code is in VB.Net). It is basically a Windows Form frame (analogous to a "Panel"?) (fraAddress) that imports a sub-screen called "AddressEdit" which can be simply viewed in the image below as the Address box that contains the street (streStreet), city (streCity), state (streState), ZIP (streZip), county (streCounty) and country (streCountry) fields. The "Description" ComboBox and "SiteID" TextBox are part of the frame (fraAddress) but NOT part of the subscreen "AddressEdit". The TextBoxes are actually called StringEdits and the List Views are called VirtualListViews in this software designer.

The issue is, anytime you use the left vertical navigation menu to switch screens (say going from "Account Detail" to "Opportunities" then back to "Account Detail"), if you are clicked inside the "AddressEdit", the scrollbar to the right (fraDragDrop frame) will move **DOWN** (as seen in the 2nd image below) when you return to the "Account Detail" screen. However, when inside any other controls, like "Structure" list, or the "Comments" TextBox, and switching screens via the left navigation menu then coming back to "Account Detail" screen, the scrollbar is **FINE** and does **NOT MOVE**.
[image]

[image]

Do any experienced .NET devs with WindowsForms/Controls have any idea what it could be?

There is a function called "Activated" that is called every time screen is switched to "AccountDetail", and I tried manually setting focus to the "AddressEdit" but to no avail... I feel like the fact that this is "AddressEdit" is a sub-screen and trying to Focus() is causing some glitch (none of the other controls are sub-screens and work fine).

Even when setting the focus() to say, the "Account name" TextBox at the top of the page manually when the page reloads and the user is clicked inside the "AddressEdit", it will indeed focus on the TextBox.... but the scrollbar will STILL slide down and block the top of the frame out of view....

I'll take any help I can on this... ;)

Comment: It is very hard to help with this without seeing any code, but it is possible that table layout panel (or whatever container is holding the controls together) for the address edit has an event trigger related to this. I would start there, otherwise just consider the order of event triggers and go through each step until you find the rogue code.

Comment: Thank you "SomeNerdAtWork" I will check out right now. I used the Visual Studio debugger and put breakpoints on all the functions and the only one that got "hit" when debugging was the "Private SubScreen_Logic Activated()" method that gets called when switching screens. I will add my the VB.Net code to the main post, and if its too long I will link the file that contains the code on my github.

Comment: Are the tab indexes in the correct order?  It really would only scroll down if a focusable control gets the focus.

Comment: @LarsTech, let me check, I noticed the "SiteID" Label and TextBox were TabOrder 29 and 30, respectively, when the AddressEdit was Tab Order 0, "Description" Label was 1, and ComboBox 2, so I'm really praying that works ... ;) Let me rebuild the .dlls and see if it does anything.

Comment: Hmm tab index update didn't seem to do it. AddressEdit box still makes the scrollbar scroll down when switching screens via the left-hand toolbar and coming back to Account Details. I will try debugging more.

Comment: Where is the FraFull frame? It's getting .focus method called on it, but you haven't labelled it in your readme.

Comment: @SomeNerdAtWork ah, that if statement with that focus() call was a test method /condition i was trying to get it to focus() on something else when the ActiveControl is some field in that AddressEdit. It didn't end up working though. I deleted that code from my github to remove confusion.